# how to start page over status bar in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, how do I make the status bar transparent, and start my page behind it?

I'm not using a nav bar, and I'm hiding the title bar. I have a header image, and instead of the status bar(top of the phone that shows carrier, battery %, time etc) being black, i'd like my page to be behind it.

Is this possible in xamarin.forms, and how would I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in info.plist

```
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
```

Best regards,

https://innovia.me

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can do

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this,false);
```

but for Android it depends on version. Here is the link

[Hiding the Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: I'm no trying to hide the status bar completely, i'm trying to have the status bar overlayed on top of my page, instead of on top of it. For example in this picture the status bar is on top of the green gradient https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwbM.png
In my case I have a image and I want the status bar to be translucent on top of it.

Comment: on iOS you will get exactly what you want. If you search stackoverflow "android activity under status bar" you will find many answers

Comment: could you link me one that is relevant to xamarin.forms? not finding much..

Comment: you will not find this for Forms. Such things have to be done in platform specific manner and probably also specific to API versions